# Pass value from one page to another using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a simple script setup using jQuery to pass a value from one page to another. The value is stored in an array. When the link is clicked, the value of the array should be sent to the community.php page, but it's not working and I'm not sure how to pull the contents of the array on the community page, any advice?

**JQUERY**

```
$("#subscribe_link").click(function () {
    $.post("community.php", { 'choices[]': ["Jon", "Susan"] });
});
```

**PHP**

```
print_r($choices);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually, you can send array in this way. the problem is that you have to access the posted data and create variables before any php executeion.

```
$("#subscribe_link").click(function () {
    $.post("community.php", { 'choices[]': ["Jon", "Susan"] });
});
```

comunity.php:

```
$choices = $_POST['choices'];
print_r($choices);
```

your ajax request will seem to do nothing unless you do something with the request data:
so, your $.post() should be:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
        $.post("community.php", { 'choices[]': ["Jon", "Susan"]}, function(data){ 
            alert(data);   
     });
});
```

Comment: you must do something with the data from the request. try this:

Comment: $.post("community.php", { 'choices[]': ["Jon", "Susan"]}, function(data){ alert(data);   });});

Comment: Ok that popped up the pages source in an alert box, what should I put in the function?

Comment: it will pop-up or whatever with the source. the only echoed code in community.php should be the result of the processing you wish it to do. here's mine for example: `$choices = $_POST['choices']if (!empty($choices)){
 print_r($choices);
}`

Comment: So how do I get a visual representation of that on the page?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26991/discussion-between-christian-rankin-and-todd)